# Android SDK crashing after using AVD on other directory

Tags: android, android-emulator

So, the Android emulator frustrating creates AVDs to the drive where the My Documents is. My Windows install drive (C) is a 120GB SSD with barely any space. I have a second 2TB drive (D).

I found in the [documentation instructions for using the android.bat](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html) tool to create AVDs wherever you want. Problem is, when I try to start these AVDs, they crash the Android SDK Emulator instantly. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Define ANDROID_SDK_HOME to point to your alternative "home" directory, this should work with both the "android" tool and the emulator.

Note that AVDs are created under $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd/ in all cases.

Hope this helps